# Not able to hide default soft keyboard programatically in Nexus 7 tab

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I am working on  an app where I need to open my own custom soft keyboard for text input.To do that I am disabling the default soft keyboard and enabling the custom one. It works fine on Jelly Bean version. However when I run the same code on Nexus 7 Tab Kitkat version it does not hide the default soft keyboard. I am using the following code for hiding the default soft Keyboard:Any idea it his not working on Kit Kat version on Nexus 7 tab?? I have researched a lot but I have not been able to figure it out.

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
public void hideKeyboard(Activity context, View v) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but still I am facing the same issue ...doesnot work on Nexus 7 Tab Kitkat

Comment: Hmmm I have used this on a Nexus 7 with Jelly Bean, works just fine. Have you looked over the answers in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)?

Comment: @ Leigh: yeah i know it works just fine with jellt bean but not with kit kat..i need a work around for this..

Answer (score 0):

Use this method.

```
public static void hideKeyboard (Context context) {

        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus ();
            if (view != null) {
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow (view.getWindowToken (), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
```

P.S. Donot pass any `view`. this will be done automatically

Comment: Yes, it will hide you softkeyboard

Comment: bhai i want to achieve navigation on custom soft keyboard like i have a soft d-pad that sends keycodes over blue tooth i want to navigate on soft keyboard on another device using those keycodes like 1 for up 2 for down 3 for  left and 4 for right...Any idea??

Comment: This is not your questions my friend

Comment: @ Murtaza Hussain: yes sir..:)

Comment: @ Murtaza Hussain: my question still stands unsolved as that piece of code did not work on kitkat..idk if i  will have to look for  some other custom soft keyboard...because in kitkat Default keyboard is not hiding on nexus 7 tab

Comment: well thats strange, because I am using same method on Android 2.3 -- 5.0. Working as expected.